# Materialized View Cassandra: Does the view still get updated if base table changes during population time?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table which is relatively big. I want to create a Materialized View in Cassandra. While the view is being populated, if the base table gets updated, will the view also get updated with those changes? How does it work? Because in order to execute a batchlog on the view, the partition on the base table will be locked, therefore it cannot wait until the population has finished. 
In my case, i will perform only inserts or deletes on the base table which simplifies things, I guess. But what if I would also perform updates? Would cassandra check the timestamps to detect somehow which value is most recent?

Comment: Please be aware that the [materialized views are marked as experimental](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201710.mbox/%3CetPan.59f24f38.438f4e99.74dc@apple.com%3E) and are not ready for production

Comment: I know, I am still not using my manual materialized table in production, but I am playing a bit as I want to gain more experience with the MVs. I want to create such a view and then simply have an integrity job that will check... well, the integrity between the view and the base. Later on I want to see what is the average delay between updating the base table and updating the view. As I said, I just want to gain more experience to see if MVs can be a viable alternative in the future to (some or) all the manual view which we need to maintain. However, I haven't found any answer to my question.